How to achieve round robin user processing in Pulsar
we're migrating from BullMQ to Pulsar and wondering how to achieve this behaviour in Pulsar
Let's say each user produces 100 tasks. We want our system to work on users tasks in round robin fashion so no one is waiting too long before something starts processing for them.
